# Flexbox disables html break tag after `</i>` tag?

Tags: flexbox, line-breaks, fontello

I've tried to insert a `<br />` tag to break the line after fontello icon and found that it's impossible when div is styled with "display:flex". Adding white space is also disabled. Adding new lines after some character is possible, but new line starts beneath `<i>` tag. Why and how to fix that? 
PS: I've noticed that in Chrome situation is better than in Firefox, but new line still starts beneath `<i>` tag.
Example:

```css
.with_flexbox{
display:flex;
color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="with_flexbox red">
With flexbox I can't use &lt;br /&gt; tag right after <i>&lt;i&gt;</i><br /> tag
</div>
<div class="without_flexbox">
Without flexbox break after <i>&lt;i&gt;</i><br />
tag works fine.
</div>
<div class="with_flexbox">
White space is also disabled right after <i>&lt;i&gt;</i>    tag. <br />And why this new line starts beneath &lt;i&gt; tag?
</div>
```

Comment: What happens here is that the `<i>` tag becomes a flex item and so does the text before and after it, as anonymous flex items, hence it won't break line in a normal sense ... so this is normal/expected behavior

Comment: ok, so all I needed was flex-direction: column;
however such behaviour suprised me (I'm the beginner); I'll keep the question for other rookies

Comment: `flex-direction: column` doesn't _fix_ anything and make the `br` _work_, it just flows the flex items vertical.

Answer (score -1):

In your third example contents of your flex container are split by `<i>` node into 3 flex items, you get 1 item that consists of:
`White space is also disabled right after`, second item `<i><i></i>` and third item `tag. <br> And why this new line starts beneath <i> tag?`. Everything looks fine, you get 3 nodes displayed horizontaly, there is a line break after word tag, just as you wrote it.

Wrapping text fragments into separate tags not only makes sense semantically but also helps you maintain your code.

If you want to stick to flexbox, you should name each node separately and use `flex-direction: column` instead of br tags, or you could set flex basis for both elements and use flex-wrap. Example snippet attached below.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.item__icon {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.item__intro {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.item__description{
  outline: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<figure class="item">
 <p class="item__intro">White space is also disabled right after</p>   
 <i class="item__icon">&lt;i&gt;</i>
 <figcaption class="item__description">tag. <br />And why this new line starts beneath &lt;i&gt; tag?</figcaption>
</div>
```

Comment: One don't use `flex-direction: column` instead of `br` tags, and `flex-direction: column` doesn't _fix_ anything, it just flows the flex items vertical.

Comment: There wasn't anything to be fixed, this snippet shows how flex items are aligned inside flex container, while also solving ops problem. You seem like a nice and helpful person.